# Medalha arqueologista deveria se chamar arqueólogo

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Aproveitando que o Gabe está empolgado com o conserto das traduções, registro mais este caso: tem uma medalha chamada "[arqueologista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/74/archaeologist)", quando o correto em português seria **arqueólogo**.

Comment: Nada mais justo. Mas eu não to necessariamente empolgado com traduções, mas sim com acertar um monte de bug que tá aberto há bastante tempo. Os de tradução são só os que eu posso consertar sozinho/mais rápido ;)

Comment: Essa foi a correção de bug mais rápida que eu já vi! Que tal consertar a [medalha Esportista](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/961/3117) também? @Gabe

Comment: @Math O Gabe acaba de bater seu próprio recorde :)

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada aí, to achando que você tá ajudando ele... rsrs. Mudando de assunto, já vi que você pôs "status-pronto" no esportista, não deveria ter a tag "bug" também? Ou pode ter "status-pronto" para coisas que não são (oficialmente) bugs?

Comment: Sei lá, @Math! Mas vou colocar bug pra ficar mais consistente.